# Why this query is resulting into TABLE ACCESS FULL not FULL INDEX SCAN?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance, create-table

```
create table indexTest(
 col1 NUMBER,
 col2 NUMBER,
 COL3 NUMBER);

 create index indexTest_INX on indexTest(col2,col3);
```

analyze index indexTest_INX validate structure;

**select col2,col3 from indextest;**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason is very simple. Columns are defined as `NULLable` so query optimizer cannot use covering index. To get **INDEX FULL SCAN** you could use:

```
create index indexTest_INX on indexTest(col2,col3,0);
                              -- at least one NOT NULL column or literal
```

or alter table columns as `NOT NULL`.

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7f073f50520f0c4bca2462c60eb36f23)**

Output:

```
select col2,col3 from indextest;

---------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name          | E-Rows |
---------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |               |        |
|   1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | INDEXTEST_INX |      1 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you are right. The index as it is, may not cover all the rows.

Comment: I deleted my answer so people won't upvote it anymore, an you'll get the votes.

Comment: @TheImpaler I really appreciate it and congratulations of "Disciplined" badge